# Tooltipster tooltip not opening on click trigger

Tags: php, wordpress, tooltipster

Tooltipster tooltip not opening on clicking the span element

Please, see the code below the one that I have tried.

**Html Code**

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1<span class="tooltipp" data-tooltip-content="#tooltip_content_1">tooltip</span>
</li>
<li>Item 1<span class="tooltipp" data-tooltip-content="#tooltip_content_2">tooltip</span>
</li>
</ul>

<div class="tooltip_templates" style="display:none;">
<span id="tooltip_content_1">Tooltip 1</span>
<span id="tooltip_content_2">Tooltip 2</span>
</div>
```

**JS code**

```
jQuery('.tooltipp').tooltipster({
    theme: 'tooltipster-shadow',
    contentCloning: true,
    trigger: 'click',
});
```

After creating a codepen for the same, tooltip is popping up there but not the content. Content is `undefined`.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/himani3010/pen/gyRyzj

Comment: Assuming you did load jQuery and include Tooltipster's CSS and JavaScript files in your page..., there should not be a comma here: `trigger: 'click',`, it should be `trigger: 'click'`

Comment: See this https://codepen.io/Moneypenny/pen/wFBrk/

Comment: Removing ',' didn't fix the issue

Comment: Have created the codepen: https://codepen.io/himani3010/pen/gyRyzj Tooltip is popping up but content is undefined